# Deep equal issue about boolean method with a Object argument

Tags: java

I am writing a class called Coord. I have created a constructor:

```
public final int r,c;  
public Coord (int r, int c){
this.r = r;
this.c = c;
}
```

I also did another two methods

```
//Creates and returns a new Coord value with the same row/column 
public Coord copy(){   
  Coord copy = new Coord (r,c);
  return copy;
}


//Given another object, is it also a Coord with the same row and column values?
public boolean equals(Object o){
  return this==o;  //this may be incorrect.
}
```

Now I can not pass some test cases as following:

```
Coord c = new Coord (5,10);
@Test (timeout=2000) public void coord() {
assertEquals(c, c.copy());
assertEquals(c, c);
assertFalse(c.equals(new Coord (2,3))); // @(5,10) != @(2,3).
assertFalse(c.equals("hello")); // must work for non-Coords.
}
```

I think the problem may arise from my boolean equals method, but I have tried a lot I still cannot pass the test. Is there a deep equal issue here? Can someone help me?

Comment: Which test cases are failing? Your implementation of `equals` is definitely wrong though. See http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17 for how to override `equal`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a deep equal issue here?

Well yes, your `equals` method just checks whether the value passed to it is the same reference. Your comment says what you *want* to do:

```
//Given another object, is it also a Coord with the same row and column values?
```

So that's what you need to implement:

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (o.getClass() != getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    Coord other = (Coord) o;
    return other.r == r && other.c == c;
}
```

I'd also encourage you to make the class `final` (in which case you can use `instanceof` instead of calling `getClass()`) and you need to implement `hashCode()` to be consistent with `equals` too. For example:

```
@Override public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 23;
    hash = hash * 31 + r;
    hash = hash * 31 + c;
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: In addition to this answer I would also add that there doesn't seem to be much point in a copy method as your class is immutable.